# pyodbc connection to mdb file

Tags: ms-access, pyodbc

I am trying to connect pyodbc to an mdb file.  I have searched this site and tried a number of things without success.  Here is an overview of my system.

Windows 7 Ultimate Service Pack 1
64 Operating System
Python 3.4.0 installed in C:\Python34\  installed using python-3.4.0.amd64.msi
pyodbc 3.0.7 installed using pyodbc-3.0.7.win-amd64-py3.4.exe
Installed AccessDatabaseEngine.exe 14.0.6119.5000  MS 2007 Office System Driver
Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Administrative Tools  Data Sources (ODBC) set to %windir%\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe
Permissions in the Registry for my user profile set to Full for Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)

The code that I am using is:
    import csv, pyodbc
    conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=c:\MDBTest\MyTestMdb.mdb;')

The error that I continue to get using a number of variations of the code is:
conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=c:\MDBTest\MyTestMdb.mdb;')
pyodbc.Error: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using a 64-bit version of Python but you have the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine installed. You either need to

- run a 32-bit version of Python, or
- remove the 32-bit version of the Access Database Engine and install the 64-bit version (available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=13255)).

Comment: Thank you very much Gord.  I didn't think I could run the 64 bit engine with my 32 bit Office, so I uninstalled Python and PYODBC and installed the 32 bit versions of them.  The code ran fine.  Thanks again!!

Comment: Thanks Gord!  Windows 10 x64 control panel showed both 32 and 64 bit odbc drivers installed, but I got the same IM002 error.  Installing 32 bit Python, Visual Studio C++ build tools, and then pyodbc fixed the problem. (pyodbc installs fine without compiling in 64 bit Python.)   Now I just need to fix my [42000] Programming Error :-).