# read access file (mdb) with pyodbc error in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, ms-access, import

I would like to read an access file (mdb) with pyodbc.
The code is supposed to be very simple:

```
import pyodbc 
DBfile = './test.mdb'
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};DBQ='+DBfile)
```

where the python script and the mdb file are in the same folder. However, I get the following error:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

where am I wrong?

thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: Resolve the current folder (`./`) and assign `DBfile` the full path.

Comment: The full path does not work "/home/..../test.mdb"

Comment: Then your script probably hasn't been granted rights to the file.

Comment: It can be open without problem in access and the error says 'file not found (0)'

Comment: But Access is not your script and ODBC driver. Your error is typical for missing rights to a physical file known to exist.

Comment: if I change the permission with sudo? I can read it with DBeaver.

Comment: I guess so, but I have no experience with Python or its ODBC library.

Comment: All the permission are correct.

Answer (score 0):

First, check the [name of the driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18810668/3527297).

Next, check that you have the correct [32- or 64-bit driver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27953437/3527297) installed.